# JFrog XRay deployed on Kubernetes with Helm chart cannot connect to RabbitMQ

Tags: kubernetes, rabbitmq, kubernetes-helm, jfrog-xray

After installing the Helm chart, the components "mongodb", "postgres" and "rabbitmq" startup successfully.

However, all 4 XRay microservices fail to start because they cannot connect to RabbitMQ:

```
[06:06:11 UTC 2018/09/07] [INFO] (jfrog.com/xray/mongo.EnsureDbSchema:9) Initializing mongo db schema...
[06:06:11 UTC 2018/09/07] [INFO] (jfrog.com/xray/mongo.EnsureDbSchema:248) Mongo schema initialization finished
...
[06:06:11 UTC 2018/09/07] [INFO] (jfrog.com/xray/xqueue/connector.connectToRabbitMQ:75) Rabbitmq connecting to uri: amqp://guest:?;W5.)lz?xaNRABBITMQ_URLJu6#{8JmI[d@xray-rdvgk-rabbitmq-ha:5672/
[06:06:11 UTC 2018/09/07] [EROR] (jfrog.com/xray/xqueue/connector.connectToRabbitMQ:78)
_____ _ _ _ _ __ __ ____ _ _ _ _ _ _
| __ \ | | | | (_) | | \/ |/ __ \ (_) | | (_) | | | | |
| |__) |__ _| |__ | |__ _| |_| \ / | | | | _ ___ _ __ ___ | |_ __ ___ ____ _ _| | __ _| |__ | | ___
| _ // _ | _ \| _ \| | __| |\/| | | | | | / __| | _ \ / _ \| __| / _ \ \ / / _ | | |/ _ | _ \| |/ _ \
| | \ \ (_| | |_) | |_) | | |_| | | | |__| | | \__ \ | | | | (_) | |_ | (_| |\ V / (_| | | | (_| | |_) | | __/
|_| \_\__ _|_ __/|_ __/|_|\__|_| |_|\___\_\ |_|___/ |_| |_|\___/ \__| \__ _| \_/ \__ _|_|_|\__ _|_ __/|_|\___|
[06:06:11 UTC 2018/09/07] [EROR] (jfrog.com/xray/xqueue/connector.connectToRabbitMQ:79) Error connecting to rabbit message queue amqp://guest:password@xray-rdvgk-rabbitmq-ha:5672/ check mq settings
```

I checked the password in commandline and admin console and it also failed. In a config file, it appeared that a blank password could have been set. However, I changed the password to the expected and verified it:

```
bash-4.4# rabbitmqctl change_password guest "password"
Changing password for user "guest" ...
bash-4.4# rabbitmqctl authenticate_user guest "password"
Authenticating user "guest" ...
Success
```

Still XRay services couldn't connect.

I also noted that rabbitmq outputs a failed authentication to the logs but it doesn't when XRay fails to connect. So it could as well be a connectivity issue - however I tried `netcat` from another pod in the same namespace to rabbitmq and it worked, so the port should be reachable.

Comment: What version of helm chart are you using?

Comment: Can you try using latest chart hosted at https://github.com/jfrog/charts/tree/master/stable/xray

Comment: I used stable / v0.4.1 but got different behaviours each time I tried. Still trying to reproduce and I will also try the master version, thanks so far.

Comment: Is your rabittmq-ha up and running fine? Do you have RBAC enabled in your K8S cluster? Can you provide more info about the cluster? Also if possible open issue in jfrog/charts.

Comment: https://github.com/jfrog/charts/blob/master/stable/xray/CHANGELOG.md#050---sep-3-2018

Comment: It seems to work out of the box with 0.5.0 from JFrog repository. If you want to post that suggestion as an answer, I will happily accept it. Thank you.

Comment: I am good as long as it worked for you.